# Image is overflowing from container with shadow

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a custom card view for my RN app, right now I'm working the on the card's cover image but it seems the image container is [overflowing the main container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67oCq.png) which seems to be caused by a conflict with box shadow ([Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG2hn.png) I removed my styling).

Here the code for my card component

```
export const LocationCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
  name,
  imageURI,
  description,
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <View style={styles.imagecontainer}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: imageURI }}
          style={{ width:"100%",height:"100%", borderRadius: 25, flexWrap:"wrap"}}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{description}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here's a picture for comparison

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use => overflow: 'hidden'

```
<View style={[styles.imagecontainer, {overflow: 'hidden'}]}>
  <Image
    source={{uri: imageURI}}
    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: 25, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
    resizeMode="cover"
  />
</View>;
```

Comment: This with a white background color for my container worked, thanks!